How to define a type based on a property value in TypeScript?
I have the following KeyMapper type that I need to fix:
type KeyMapper<T extends object> = {
  targetKey: keyof T;
  mapper: {
    [key: string]: T[keyof T];
  };
};

In the following definition, even if I specify the targetKey in the object, no error occurs
type ButtonProps = {
  hierarchy: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
  styleSemantic: 'info' | 'success' | 'alert' | 'warning';
};

const keyMapperArray: KeyMapper<ButtonProps>[] = [
  {
    targetKey: 'hierarchy',
    mapper: {
      filled: 'primary'
    }
  },
  {
    targetKey: 'styleSemantic',
    mapper: {
      error: 'primary' // This should produce an error in TypeScript
    }
  }
];

The second value in array keyMapperArray should produce an error, because primary is not a valid value for the styleSemantic key.
const keyMapperArray: KeyMapper<ButtonProps>[] = [
  {
    // The 'hierarchy' key defines the available values in the mapper ('primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary')
    targetKey: 'hierarchy',
    mapper: {
      // This should work because 'primary' is a valid value for the 'hierarchy' key
      filled: 'primary'
    }
  },
  {
    // The 'styleSemantic' key defines the available values in the mapper ('info', 'success', 'alert', 'warning')
    targetKey: 'styleSemantic',
    mapper: {
      // This should not work, as 'primary' is not a valid value for the 'styleSemantic' key
      error: 'primary'
    }
  }
];


Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to distribute the operation of KeyMapper over unions in keyof T, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or, more likely, find a question this duplicates). If not, what's missing?

This works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.
